# Как получить значения двоичных данных 1C, в поле таблицы SQL

Tags: 1с

1С:Платформа 8.3 связана с SQl Server через (Администрирование серверов 1с предприятия). Синхронизация есть,все хорошо!  Таблица любого документа в 1с имеет совсем другое представление полей в SQL. И данные таблицы представлены как (<Двоичные данные>) В чем ВОПРОС! Каким образом преобразовать <Двоичные данные>, что бы получить данные 1С!?
Например: Есть поле "Поле1"  с данными в SQL -|<Двоичные данные>| ,а нужно |Ручка|

Answer (score 1):

> Base64Строка (Base64String) Синтаксис:
>
> Base64Строка(<Значение>) Параметры:
>
> <Значение> (обязательный)
>
> Тип: ДвоичныеДанные.  Двоичные данные, которые необходимо закодировать
>   по алгоритму base64.
>
> Возвращаемое значение:
>
> Тип: Строка.

Например:

```
Текст = Base64Строка(ДВОИЧНЫЕДАННЫЕ);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Функция ПолучитьGUIDПоУникальномуИдентификатору(UUID1)
    UUID=ВРЕГ(UUID1);
    ч1 = Сред(UUID,20,4);
    ч2 = Сред(UUID,25,12);
    ч3 = Сред(UUID,15,4);
    ч4 = Сред(UUID,10,4);
    ч5 = Сред(UUID,1,8);
    Возврат "0x" + ч1 + ч2 + ч3 + ч4 + ч5;
КонецФункции
```

Посмотри 
 [Создание документа в другой БД](http://www.1cpp.ru/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1291110656/14) 
[Как перевести ГУИД в число и обратно?](http://www.forum.mista.ru/topic.php?id=378881)

[Code First и Linq to EF на примере 1С версии 8.3 часть II](http://infostart.ru/public/402038/)

Еще

```
ТипhexBinary    = ФабрикаXDTO.Тип("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "hexBinary"); 

    ДвоичныеДанные      = ФабрикаXDTO.Создать(ТипhexBinary,Хэш.ХешСумма);
      Сообщить(ДвоичныеДанные.ЛексическоеЗначение);
```

А вообще